# Cannot import antlr4 lexer grammar in combined grammar using Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, maven, antlr4, eclipse-kepler

Given:

**Simple.g4**

```
grammar Simple;

import SimpleLexer;

prog : entry+ EOF;
entry : a semi tail;
semi : ':';
tail : TAIL;
a : 'a';
W:;
```

**SimpleLexer.g4**

```
lexer grammar SimpleLexer;

TAIL : [a-z]+;
```

They are both in a same package under 'src/main/antlr4'.

Maven plugins:

```xml
 <plugins>
  ...
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/generated-sources/antlr4</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>          
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>antlr4</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[4.2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>antlr4</goal>                                         
                                    </goals>                                        
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Version of the antlr eclipse plugin:

```
ANTLR 4 SDK Feature 0.1.1.201401151138  antlr4ide.sdk.feature.group
```

Eclipse version:

```
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
```

The error on import statement in Simple.g4 that eclipse gives is:

```
 can't find or load grammar 'SimpleLexer' from 'Simple.g4'
```

Environment works for single file grammars.

Comment: you Don't need the build-helper-maven-plugin to add the generated folder cause the plugin will do that on it's own. In Eclipse you might need to add the target/generated/ folder by hand in your eclipse project. This is a lacking feature of the antlr4 maven plugin.

Comment: Yes, removing the helper plug-in gives now the more promising error:     `error(113): Simple.g4:3:7: combined grammar 'Simple' and imported lexer grammar 'SimpleLexer' both generate 'SimpleLexer'`. Suggestions?

Comment: ANTLR 4.2 should fully support m2e without any additional configuration. You can remove both the `build-helper-maven-plugin` *and* the entire `pluginManagement` block. The specific commit that adds this feature is [`f2966aa`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/commit/f2966aaa80ad77c4ac6027f2cefd1e323a8f1bc4).

Comment: True, already imports and runs the grammars with no warnings or errors. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the half story. The eclipse plug-in actually uses antlr 4.1 and automatically runs builds on save which additionally makes the situation strange and hides the actual result when maven is run in console or just used as pure maven eclipse support. So I removed the eclipse antlr4 plugin also. Besides this imported lexers should be in **src/main/antlr4/imports** and I renamed the lexer name from **SimpleLexer** to something else because antlr tries to generate java files with duplicate names. So don't name your grammars for example G.g4 and GLexer.g4, this will generate error 113

Comment: Don't use implicitly defined tokens in the parser like `:` and `a` but put those in the lexer.